# Getting stuck and confused setting up my first Hoodie app

Tags: hoodie

Been trying to setup a simple Hoodie app and its been a very troublesome days for me.
To get more eyes on my issues, I'm submitting the issues that I'd submitted in Hoodie server issues but couldn't get any replies yet.

So here are the issues I want someone to look into:

- https://github.com/hoodiehq/hoodie-server/issues/510
- https://github.com/hoodiehq/hoodie-server/issues/511
- https://github.com/hoodiehq/hoodie-server/issues/512

But the one that will take me forward is this one:

- https://github.com/hoodiehq/hoodie-server/issues/513

Answer (score 2):

I’m very sorry for the trouble you run into. I’m one of Hoodie’s core contributors, I’m happy to help you out.

First, your node version is very out of date. Can you please install the latest node from https://nodejs.org/en/?

Also you are using the old hoodie version. I’m very sorry for the confusion, we are currently transitioning to a new Hoodie, and the old version is still referenced a lot on our website and the docs.

After you installed the new Node version, follow the setup instructions at https://github.com/hoodiehq/hoodie. Here is a simple example app that you can check out to see Hoodie works https://github.com/hoodiehq/hoodie-app-tracker. And the work-in-progress docs are here: http://docs.hood.ie/camp/ (note the `/camp` path)